# SQL Server 2008 database mail using YANDEX

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mail, yandex, sqlmail

I am trying to send mail with my yandex mail account on database mail. Actually it was working for a long time. Last 1 month I cannot send mail with my yandex account. Always it gives that error message,

> Error,16492,The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 10 (2014-11-08T17:20:25). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (time out ).

The mail account works with Microsoft Outlook, but it does not work with database mail. I am also using SSL secure connection. Which is in the configuration of database mail account?

Thank you.

Comment: Iam using mssql 2008 version

Answer (score 1):

It's a late response but it is a true solution.
With Yandex kindly use SSL port number 587 instead of 465.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very important information for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot Yandex IMAP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4KS.png)

Also add IMAP settings, SMTP does not work without it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33123150)